# Put Condition at Specific Time Range by XML Node as Parameter

Tags: xml, date, vbscript

The problem is here I am going to remove the XML parent Node by its child node's value, and the value is `ProcessDate` as a date format.

The condition I want to make is:

- There was a lot of data in XML format, and when user execute the VBScript, it is automatically remove the node which the `ProcessDate` is older than week ago.

Here below the code:

```vb
Dim strFile
Dim strQuery

weekdate = Day(Date < Date-7) & "/" & Month(Date) & "/" & Year(Date) 

strFile = "D:\Log.xml"

strQuery = "/Logs/Log[ProcessDate = '" & weekdate & "']"

Set xmlDoc = WScript.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.Async = "False"
xmlDoc.Load(strFile)

Set colNodes = xmlDoc.selectNodes(strQuery)
For Each objNode In colNodes
    objNode.ParentNode.removeChild(objNode)
Next

xmlDoc.Save strFile
```

Below is the images sample

[image: Sample Images]

Comment: [Code or output as an image is not helpful](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/692942), the XML output could have easily been posted as a code-block, not an image.

Comment: Im sorry, but thanks for the feed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `Day(Date < Date-7)` doesn't do what you seem to think. `Date < Date-7` evaluates to the boolean value `False` (because the current date is never less than the date seven days ago), and `Day(False)` always returns 30. Also, VBScript doesn't seem to support XPath 2.0 functions, so you can't transform the XML string values to dates for a comparison via XPath.

You need to get the value of the `<ProcessDate>` nodes, convert it to a date, and remove its parent node from its grandparent node if the date is more than 7 days ago. Try something like this:

```vb
For Each n xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//ProcessDate")
    If CDate(n.Text) < Date - 7 Then
        n.ParentNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(n.ParentNode)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was helpful. The function do the right things